# Unable to query Yahoo! Fantasy Sports API

Tags: c#, asp.net, yql

I am trying to pull details from Yahoo! Fantasy Sports API using OAuth2.0. I got the `access_token` to query using YQL. My code

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + response.access_token);
    var query = "select%20*%20from%20fantasysports.games%20where%20game_key%3D'nfl'"; 
    Response.Write(query);
    var url = String.Format("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q={0}&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=", query);
    output = client.DownloadString(url);
}
```

My response

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 0,
        "created": "2015-09-27T17:39:48Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "diagnostics": {
            "publiclyCallable": "true",
            "url": {
                "execution-start-time": "4",
                "execution-stop-time": "137",
                "execution-time": "133",
                "http-status-code": "401",
                "http-status-message": "Authorization Required",
                "content": "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/games;game_keys=nfl"
            },
            "user-time": "138",
            "service-time": "133",
            "build-version": "0.2.240"
        },
        "results": null
    }
}
```

I am getting an **Authorization Required** status message.

I think it has got to do something with my request header. Can someone help me on understanding why my request is rejected here?

Comment: `Response.Write(query);` looks very dodgy.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: no other simpler way Yahoo! wont let me test locally for Fantasy Sports API

Comment: @naveen, did you get this to work so you could pull public data from Yahoo Sports using c#?  I am working on it, but finding it very difficult.  I am trying to run this YQL command: select * from fantasysports.players where game_key=371 and this is supposed ot be the RESTful command I use: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20fantasysports.players%20where%20game_key%3D371&diagnostics=true  so far your post here seems the most promising, but i feel like you have not listed your entire code, only the snippet, and so i am not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahoo! has two OAuth Authorization Flows

1. Two legged flow
2. Three legged flow

Yahoo notes,

> Most of the Fantasy API data relies on 3-legged OAuth, as much of the
> data is specific to a certain Yahoo! user. However, you can use
> 2-legged OAuth to request purely public data. 2-legged OAuth
> effectively boils down to making a request without setting an access
> token through the default PHP OAuth library, or effectively using your
> consumer key/secret as the token.

So we should go for [three-legged flow of OAuth authorization](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html) as exactly described in the Yahoo! documentation. At the end of the authorization flow, you will get a `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`.

Yahoo have provided this code in C# ([Link here](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html#oauth_csharp)).

```
public static string GetUserDataFromYahoo(string requestEndPoint, string token, string tokenSecret)
{
    var data = String.Empty;
    var uri = new Uri(requestEndPoint);
    string url, param;
    var oAuth = new OAuthBase();
    var nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
    var timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
    var signature = oAuth.GenerateSignature(
        uri, 
        consumerKey,
        consumerSecret,
        token,
        tokenSecret, 
        "GET", 
        timeStamp, 
        nonce,
        OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, 
        out url, 
        out param);
    data = String.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}", url, param, signature);
    var requestParametersUrl = String.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}", url, param, signature);
    var request = WebRequest.Create(requestParametersUrl);
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return data;
}
```

This code uses this [OAuthBase.cs class](https://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs).

And when you use this code, you will get a

> OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR

That is because, OAuthBase.cs has a [bug that's been noted here](https://code.google.com/p/oauth/issues/detail?id=138#c4). To correct that you have to do this.

> Line 199 (in NormalizeRequestParameters method) must change from:
>
> ```
> sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", p.Name, p.Value);
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", UrlEncode(p.Name), UrlEncode(p.Value));
> ```

Happy coding!

Comment: posting this for fellow coders who might encounter these issues while pulling data from yahoo.

Comment: OAuthBase.cs link is dead try this https://code.google.com/archive/p/oauth/issues/138#c4

Comment: Please explain how to use GetUserDataFromYahoo.  Are you saying use it in conjunction with the Yahoo code?  As the third leg?

Comment: I anyone still us9ing this kind of code to pull yahoo fantasy data?  Is there a new and better method?  I am just looking to get a list of all players, stats etc.  basically the results of this command inthe YQL console:

Comment: select * from fantasysports.players where game_key='371'

Comment: havent used it in two years

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you have not correctly received the `access_token`.  This is why you get `Authorization Required` on the call to the server.

You need to check your code that gets the `access_token`

Comment: I am getting access_token, refresh_token the whole thing. Its something with the call.